# Why are my text values returing -460?

Tags: java, string, int

This is a continuance of my previous post but on a different main topic. I don't know why my program reads the file and returns my error value of -460. There are 100 ints in my text file and 99 of them get returned as -460 and the last number in the file gets read correctly. I don't know what is going on! please help! Thank you!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class projectFour
{
    public static int [] global_numbers;
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        read_file();
        print_numbers(global_numbers);
    }
    public static void read_file()
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("randomNumbers.txt"); 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            int amountOfNumbersInFile = convertingStringToInt(scan.nextLine()); // read the first line which is 100 to set array size
            global_numbers = new int[amountOfNumbersInFile]; // set the array size equal to the first line read which is 100
            for (int index = 0; index < amountOfNumbersInFile; index++) 
            {
            String line = scan.nextLine(); 
            global_numbers [index] = convertingStringToInt(line); 
            }      
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static int convertingStringToInt(String numbers) //what does string "number" equal? why/where is it declared? where is its value coming from?!?
    {  
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(numbers);
        } catch(NumberFormatException n) {
            return -460;
        }         
    }
    public static void print_numbers(int [] numbers) // passing in an array called numbers but how does this array  have values associated  to it!?!
    {
      int max = numbers.length;
      for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            System.out.println(numbers[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're obviously getting an exception for every single number (except the last) and return -460 in the catch block. The parseInt works on a single number only, you can't send an entire line  as an argument and expect t to work.

Comment: So rather than catching the exception and throwing away the useful information it provides to you, look at what's in the exception. Clearly we can't help you without knowing the content of `randomNumbers.txt`.

Comment: By far, the best way to debug this sort of thing is to *debug it*. Use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code, statement by statement, looking at what's in the string before you try to convert it, looking at the contents of the exception, etc. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced technique; it's an absolutely basic step for the beginner programmer.

Comment: If you look at your text file, and it looks like 100 lines with one number per line, then your problem is likely **spaces**. `Integer.parseInt()` is very strict. `"42"` is a valid number, but `" 42"` and `"42 "` are not. Perhaps you could try trimming the spaces, by changing code to `return Integer.parseInt(numbers.trim());`

Comment: @Andreas - yes, either some whitespace character or even a newline character (not sure how nextline works though)

Comment: changing code to return Integer.parseInt(numbers.trim()); was successful

Comment: thanks a lot everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class projectFour
{
    public static int [] global_numbers;
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        read_file();
        print_numbers(global_numbers);
    }
    public static void read_file()
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("randomNumbers.txt"); 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            int amountOfNumbersInFile = convertingStringToInt(scan.nextLine());
            global_numbers = new int[amountOfNumbersInFile];
            for (int index = 0; index < amountOfNumbersInFile; index++) 
            {
                String line = scan.nextLine(); 
                global_numbers [index] = convertingStringToInt(line); 
            }      
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static int convertingStringToInt(String numbers)
    {  
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(numbers.trim());
        } catch(NumberFormatException n) {
            return -460;
        }         
    }
    public static void print_numbers(int [] numbers) 
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            System.out.println(numbers[i]); 
    }
}
```